# Deploying a sharepoint web service with Powershell

Tags: powershell, web-services

Is it possible to install a web service to sharepoint 2010 using powershell rather than using a solution package? I'm currently doing this via a mapped folder/ISAPI approach inside a feature but would like to script this with powershell.

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Do not do that!!

There are many considerations that you need to take into account: multiple web front end servers, proper web.config updates, security, etc. The solution deployment framework in SharePoint already handles all of the issues.

What reason do you have for not using the framework?

Comment: Good point - I had completely overlooked multiple WFE scenarios! (Bad me) - You do indeed need a pretty good reason not use WSPs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it written in a feature then you can certainly install and activate the feature through powershell.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442691.aspx